# Why are llamas/alpacas so popular in anime?

Tags: tropes

This has been something that has been bugging me for a while:

**Why are there so many llamas in anime and in anime fan culture?**

Some specific anime examples:

[image: Stein's Gate]
[image: Paca Plus (Game)]
[image]

You can buy alpacas at conventions too:

[image]

Where is this coming from? **Why do I keep seeing llamas?!** I don't believe llamas/alpaca are even native to Japan? (Although I did find [a farm in Nasu](http://www.tripadvisor.ie/Attraction_Review-g1121057-d1723782-Reviews-Nasu_Alpaca_Farm-Nasu_machi_Nasu_gun_Tochigi_Prefecture_Kanto.html))

Comment: please forgive my lack of knowledge on how to distinguish between the two

Comment: I found a similar topic of this on reddit, and theres an answer there that's rather interesting conserning the alpacamania.

See here: https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/1mfgs8/why_are_alpacas_so_popular_in_animeconventions/cc8tvok

Comment: I believe it's alpaca, not llama, which is popular in Japan culture. I also often see the Japanese refer to alpaca while watching videos on NicoDou... though I'm not sure if [NicoNicoPedia](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%83%91%E3%82%AB) (Japanese) could give a hint why alpaca is popular there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@ChenOrihara's link seems to be correct - it's not just an anime thing, there is an overall trend in Japan that sees alpacas being included in unlikely situations.

[There's even a company that leases alpacas for weddings:](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-3163656/New-craze-Japan-sees-couples-hiring-ALPACAS-witnesses-wedding.html)

[image]

Their popularity may have been triggered when the [alpaca farm in Nasu](http://www.tripadvisor.ie/Attraction_Review-g1121057-d1723782-Reviews-Nasu_Alpaca_Farm-Nasu_machi_Nasu_gun_Tochigi_Prefecture_Kanto.html) was built in 1999 - [bringing 200 alpacas into the country](http://en.japantravel.com/view/the-largest-alpaca-farm-in-japan). Subsequent farms have been built also. The Nasu farm currently has [>400 alpacas](http://kaorisquarefeet.blogspot.ie/2014/08/the-alpaca-farm-in-nasu.html)

Comment: I **DO** want an apalca for my wedding